Why is the Docker image built in GitHub Actions so large?
In the same project, the Docker image I built on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) is 1.56GB, while the image built on GitHub Actions is 11.7GB. Why is there such a difference, even though I used the same Dockerfile?
My code is very simple, it just includes many additional Python third-party packages. Please tell me what I should do.
dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install poetry

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock /app/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi COPY . /app

CMD ["python3", "main.py" ]

workflows:
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Log in to GitHub Container Registry
      run: echo "${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN }}" | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

    - name: Build Docker image
      run: docker build -t ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/${{ github.repository }}/${{env.IMAGE_NAME}}:latest .

    - name: show image size
      run: docker images

    - name: Push Docker image to GHCR
      run: docker push ghcr.io/${{ github.repository_owner }}/${{ github.repository }}/${{env.IMAGE_NAME}}:latest

Local Build
GitHub Actions Build
I want the Docker image built on GitHub Actions to be the same size as the image built locally.

I wrote a Python tool and discovered the issue: the Python third-party package "sentence-transformers" automatically downloads NVIDIA-related packages in Docker. This causes the Docker image to be quite large. So if you're encountering a similar problem, please check the Python third-party packages you've installed to see if they are automatically downloading something you're not aware of.


Good detective work! Why is that different on GitLab than you're getting locally though?

Uninstalling sentence-transformers solved the issue, but I still don't understand why the Docker image built locally is different from the one built in GitHub Actions. They both run in Docker.

Random thought: Is this based on the host gpu?

Maybe it's possible.

@beefoxfox were you able to figure out an alternative way ? I am using sentence-transformers so don't want to uninstall it.
